# Android, how to align text at a specific point over an image?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am learning android programming and setting myself a task to get to grips with layouts. I am trying to create a virtual "Magic 8 Ball".

My aim is to have some random text appear in the white circle where the 8 would normally appear.

How do go about aligning the text so that on different devices the text always appears in the same relative position to the black ball, so is always within the white circle?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do
[image]

Here is my code so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    tools:context="uk.co.simoncarr.magic8ball.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img8Ball"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/magic8ball"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="111dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="296dp"
            android:text="The Anser is Yes"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="447dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post (a visual representation) your intended result along with what you have so far

Comment: I have added my layout code and an image of what I have so far

Comment: If the image is going to be full screen always , then you can try to have a image whose white circle center will always be the center on device and then use a textview that will be horizontally and vertically center aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question I should comment on the fact that the elements inside you ConstraintLayout are not constrained in any way so when you run the app they will not keep the positions you have given them in the layout editor. You should fix this before doing anything else.

One approach you could look at could be to have 2 circle drawables, one with a black background and one with a white one and place one on top of the other. This way you could use the relatively new "Circular Positioning" feature in ConstraintLayout as outlined in [this](http://androidkt.com/constraintlayout-circular-positioning/) post. This will give you a lot of flexibility and power over choosing the positioning of the white circle in relation to the black.

Comment: thanks this sounds like an interesting approach I will give it a try. Not sure why some people with small genitals have marked this question down and not left any comment why. May be this is the new way that Stack overflow rocks, get rid of anyone knew to a language so that only the big boys who already know what they are doing can play together. I think I'm going to mark down some random posts, so that it looks like I know what I am doing.

Comment: Some people like the power I guess. Make sure you have the most recent beta of ConstraintLayout